# Is it possible to add overlays on Google's Map API similar to MKOverlay in MapKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-mobile

We are experimenting with the new google maps API for iOS and we need to be able to add overlays similar to what MKOverlay does in Apple's MapKit.

Answer (score 0):

```
      let poly = GMSMutablePath()

    poly .addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude))

    let polygon = GMSPolygon()
        polygon .path = poly
    polygon.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    polygon.strokeWidth = 4
     polygon.strokeColor = UIColor .redColor()
    polygon.map = self.mapView
```